# C# client-server sockets communication in threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I have created these applications. One is server socket which consists of main thread responsible for creating client/server connection and creating other threads:

- thread for producing messages
- thread for listening for received messages from client
- thread to send produced messages by server

If there is connection disrupted server frees any resources and waits for new connections in a loop.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class SynchronousSocketListener {

    private Socket handler; //socket handlet
    private byte[] bytes; // Data buffer for incoming data.  
    private List < String > messagesToSend;
    private Mutex messagesToSendMutex;

    public SynchronousSocketListener() {
        messagesToSendMutex = new Mutex();

        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            messagesToSend = new List < String > ();
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        bytes = new Byte[1024];
        handler = null;
    }

    private void addMessageToQueue(string message) {

        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            messagesToSend.Add(message);
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private string readMessageFromQueue() {

        string ret = null;
        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            if (messagesToSend.Count > 0)
                ret = messagesToSend[0];
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private void removeMessageFromQueue(string messageToRemove) {

        string ret = null;
        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            if (messagesToSend.Count > 0)
                messagesToSend.Remove(messageToRemove);
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private void threadForGeneratingMessages() {
        while (true) {
            addMessageToQueue(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    private void sendingThread(CancellationToken ct) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    // Clean up here, then...
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine("Task sending is cancelled");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("System.OperationCanceledException");
                return;
            }

            if (messagesToSend.Count <= 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("No more messages to send");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Server is going to write some data for client");

            //send pending messages to client

            string dataToSendNow = messagesToSend[0];
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSendNow + "<EOF>");

            try {
                // Send the data through the socket.  

                int bytesSent = handler.Send(msg);
                messagesToSend.Remove(dataToSendNow);

                Console.WriteLine("Server send data");
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("returning from sendingThread sockEx");
                return;

            } catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //socketError = true;
                Console.WriteLine("returning from sendingThread objDisEx");
                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void receivingThread(CancellationToken ct) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    // Clean up here, then...
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine("Task receiving is cancelled");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("System.OperationCanceledException");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Server is waiting for a new message to arrive: ");
            try {
                if (!handler.Connected) throw new SocketException();
                //handler.Send(new byte[] { 0 });
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                Console.WriteLine("Server has received message = {0}",
                    receivedData);

                /*
                //do some stuff with the message
                .
                .
                .
                */

            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //socketError = true;
                return;
            } catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //socketError = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartListening() {
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
        // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the
        // host running the application.  
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

        while (true) {

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and
            // listen for incoming connections. 

            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Console.WriteLine("New connection can be made");

            try {
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11100);
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(10);

                // Start listening for connections.  

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.  
                handler = listener.Accept();
                Console.WriteLine("New connection is made");

                var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

                //when new connection is made create new thread for sending data through socket
                var task_send = Task.Run(() => {
                    sendingThread(ct);

                }, tokenSource2.Token);

                var tokenSource3 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken ct3 = tokenSource3.Token;

                //when new connection is made create new thread for receiving data through socket
                var task = Task.Run(() => {
                    receivingThread(ct3);
                }, tokenSource3.Token);

                while (true) {
                    if (task.IsCompleted || task_send.IsCompleted) { //activelly oolling the field to find out, wether threads has been cancelled/returned
                        Console.WriteLine("some tasks is Completed");
                        tokenSource2.Cancel();
                        tokenSource3.Cancel();
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();
                        break; //breaking from polling loop to prepare for a new connection
                    }
                }

            } catch (SocketException se) {
                Console.WriteLine(se.ToString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            listener.Dispose(); //disposing listener so that new one can be created
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static int Main(String[] args) {
        SynchronousSocketListener synSocList = new SynchronousSocketListener();
        var task_generateMsg = Task.Run(
            (synSocList.threadForGeneratingMessages));

        synSocList.StartListening();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

client's app structure is basically the same as server's with exception, that it is actively trying to connect to server, if connection has been disrupted:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class SynchronousSocketClient {
    private Socket sender; //socket
    private byte[] bytes; // Data buffer for incoming data.  
    private List < String > messagesToSend;
    private Mutex messagesToSendMutex;

    public SynchronousSocketClient() {
        messagesToSendMutex = new Mutex();

        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            messagesToSend = new List < String > ();
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        bytes = new Byte[1024];
        sender = null;
    }

    private void addMessageToQueue(string message) {

        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            messagesToSend.Add(message);
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private string readMessageFromQueue() {

        string ret = null;
        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            if (messagesToSend.Count > 0)
                ret = messagesToSend[0];
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private void removeMessageFromQueue(string messageToRemove) {

        string ret = null;
        try {
            messagesToSendMutex.WaitOne();
            if (messagesToSend.Count > 0)
                messagesToSend.Remove(messageToRemove);
        } finally {
            messagesToSendMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    private void threadForGeneratingMessages() {
        while (true) {
            addMessageToQueue(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    private void sendingThread(CancellationToken ct) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    // Clean up here, then...
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine("Task sending is cancelled");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("System.OperationCanceledException");
                return;
            }

            if (messagesToSend.Count <= 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("No more messages to send");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Client is going to write some data for client");

            //send pending messages to client

            string dataToSendNow = messagesToSend[0];
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSendNow + "<EOF>");

            try {
                // Send the data through the socket.  

                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
                messagesToSend.Remove(dataToSendNow);

                Console.WriteLine("Client send data");
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("returning from sendingThread sockEx");
                return;

            } catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //socketError = true;
                Console.WriteLine("returning from sendingThread objDisEx");
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    private void receivingThread(CancellationToken ct) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    // Clean up here, then...
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    Console.WriteLine("Task receiving is cancelled");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("System.OperationCanceledException");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Client is waiting for a new message to arrive: ");
            try {
                if (!sender.Connected) throw new SocketException();
                //sender.Send(new byte[] { 0 });
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                Console.WriteLine("Client has received message = {0}",
                    receivedData);

                /*
                //do some stuff with the message
                .
                .
                .
                */

            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //socketError = true;
                return;
            } catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //socketError = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendingThread() {
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("Write some data for server");

            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line + "<EOF>");

            try {
                // Send the data through the socket.  
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                Console.WriteLine("data are send");
                // Receive the response from the remote device. 
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                socketError = false;
                return;

            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    volatile private bool socketError = false;

    private void receivingThread() {

        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("receiving:");
            try {

                if (!sender.Connected) throw new SocketException();
                sender.Send(new byte[] {
                    0
                });
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                socketError = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartClient() {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.  

        while (true) {
            // Connect to a remote device.  

            try {
                // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
                // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.  
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11100);

                // Create a TCP/IP  socket.  
                sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.  
                try {

                    sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                    Console.WriteLine("Client has made connection to the server");

                    /*
                    try
                    {
                        task_send.Wait();
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException ae)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ae.ToString());
                        foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                    */

                    var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

                    //when new connection is made create new thread for sending data through socket
                    var task_send = Task.Run(() => {
                        sendingThread(ct);

                    }, tokenSource2.Token);

                    var tokenSource3 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    CancellationToken ct3 = tokenSource3.Token;

                    //when new connection is made create new thread for receiving data through socket
                    var task = Task.Run(() => {
                        receivingThread(ct3);
                    }, tokenSource3.Token);

                    while (true) {
                        if (task.IsCompleted || task_send.IsCompleted) { //activelly oolling the field to find out, wether threads has been cancelled/returned
                            Console.WriteLine("some tasks is Completed");
                            tokenSource2.Cancel();
                            tokenSource3.Cancel();
                            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                            sender.Close();
                            break; //breaking from polling loop to prepare for a new connection
                        }
                    }

                    /*
                    var task_send = Task.Run(
                        (sendingThread));

                    var task = Task.Run(
                        (receivingThread));
                    
                    */
                    /*
                    try
                    {
                        task.Wait();
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException ae)
                    {
                        foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }*/

                    /*

                    bool task_receiving_res = false;
                    //int timeout = 60000;
                    Task<bool> task_receiving = new Task<bool>(() => receivingThread());
                    task_receiving.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("here0");

                    if (await Task.WhenAny(task_receiving, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)) == task_receiving)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("here-0");
                        // task completed within timeout
                        task_receiving_res = task_receiving.Result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new TimeoutException();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("here");

                    bool task_sending_res = false;
                    //int timeout = 60000;
                    Task<bool> task_sending = new Task<bool>(() => sendingThread());
                    task_sending.Start();
                    if (await Task.WhenAny(task_sending, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)) == task_sending)
                    {
                        // task completed within timeout
                        task_sending_res = task_sending.Result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new TimeoutException();
                    }
                    */
                    /*
                    Console.WriteLine("here1");

                    while (true) {
                        if (socketError) {
                            /*task.Dispose();
                            task_send.Dispose();
                            
                            */
                    /*
                    socketError = false;
                            throw new Exception("restart connection");
                        }
                        
                    }*/

                    /*
                    while (true)
                    {
                        */
                    /*Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                        sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());*/
                    /*
                    // Encode the data string into a byte array.  
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

                    // Send the data through the socket.  
                    int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
                    */
                    // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                    /*int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
                    */
                    /*
                    bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
                    */
                    /*

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);


                }*/

                    // Release the socket.  
                    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    sender.Close();

                } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {
                    Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
                } catch (SocketException se) {
                    Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

    }

    public static int Main(String[] args) {
        SynchronousSocketClient sc = new SynchronousSocketClient();

        var task_generateMsg = Task.Run(
            (sc.threadForGeneratingMessages));

        sc.StartClient();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How could these code be written do be more efficient? Is this safe, or are there any problems with these code (besides efficiency)?

---

Edit:
I have a problem with the code:
sometimes receivingThread is looping without halting at handler/sender.Receive() function, it seems to read 0 bytes even though other side does not send anything. How can this be corrected?

Comment: Yes, this can be much more efficient. Any real servers should *almost never* use dedicated threads for clients, since threads are *extremely* expensive and limiting; but more generally - network servers are *really really complicated and hard to get right*. Honestly, you *don't need to do this yourself* - Kestrel makes an excellent host for general TCP servers, and all you need to do is provide a handler that can consume from a `Pipe` - but whether this is *worth your time* depends on whether this is "real" code, vs just for fun. I have a 4-part blog series discussing this topic in...

Comment: ...much more depth than I could even remotely cover here, including github examples etc - starting here: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Comment: well there will be just one client connected to the server, I am aware it is inefficient, but now I would like to know, whether it can be unsafe